# file_get_contents(): Content-type not specified assuming application/x-www-form-urlencoded in

Tags: php, api

Здоровки, в общем сделал метод для API - вроде даже работает, но постоянно выдает эту ошибку, посмотрел в интернете у многих разное решение, обьясните пожалуйста что именно мне нужно исправить и почему. Спасибо:

Вот мой метод:

```
public static function getReportList(): array
    {
        $method = 'GetForecastList';
        $config = config::get_config();
        $request = array(
            'token' => $config['dirtoken'],
            'method' => $method,
            'locale' => 'ru',
        );
        $request = json_encode($request);
        $opts = array(
            'http' => array(
                'method' => "POST",
                'content' => $request,
            )
        );
        $context = stream_context_create($opts);
        $result = file_get_contents('https://api.direct.yandex.ru/live/v4/json/', 0, $context);
        $result = json_decode($result, true);
        return $result;
```

Вот ошибка:

> Notice: file_get_contents(): Content-type not specified assuming
> application/x-www-form-urlencoded in
> /Users/leonidbasov/Projects/zzz.lk2.ru/engine/direct.php on line 185

185 строчка это:

```
$result = file_get_contents('https://api.direct.yandex.ru/live/v4/json/', 0, $context);
```

Спасибо!

Comment: Добавьте заголовок `Content-type` в `$context['http']['header']`

Comment: Добавитл: "Content-type" => "application/json", тоже самое

Comment: НА "Content-type" => "application/json; charset=utf-8", тоже не исчезает (

Comment: покажите исправленную версию

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Добавитл: "Content-type" => "application/json",

> НА "Content-type" => "application/json; charset=utf-8", тоже не исчезает (

В массиве контекста заголовок должен передаваться строкой, а не массивом. Вот вам решение:

```php
public static function getReportList(): array
{
    $method = 'GetForecastList';
    $config = config::get_config();
    $request = array(
        'token' => $config['dirtoken'],
        'method' => $method,
        'locale' => 'ru',
    );
    $headers = array(
        'Content-Type: application/json',
    );
    $request = json_encode($request);
    $opts = array(
        'http' => array(
            'method' => "POST",
            'header' => implode("\r\n", $headers),
            'content' => $request,
        )
    );
    $context = stream_context_create($opts);
    $result = file_get_contents('https://api.direct.yandex.ru/live/v4/json/', 0, $context);
    $result = json_decode($result, true);
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, сделал решение таким вариантом: 'http' => array(
                'header' => 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8',